# Javascript game

Tags: javascript

I just made this tiny game, where a user can click. And he can see his clicks, just like 'cookieclicker'.

Everything works, except for one thing.

I tried to shorten my code, by making a variable of lines of code, that i repeat alot of times.

```
document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;
```

This works perfectly, to show the clicks the user has done. But when i try to make it into a variable, it doesn't work. 
Example :

```
 var hpdraw = document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;
```

Is there a reason why i can't shorten the text by making it a variable? Or am i doing something wrong?

The whole javascript below :

```
<style>
    #clicker {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style.css">

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="clicker">
            <button id="clickerbutton" onclick="onKlik()"> Click me!</button>
                 <p id="clicktekst"></p><br>
                 <p id="hp-bar-p"></p><br>
                 <p id="kills"></p><br>
            <button id="upgrade" onclick="upgradeKlik()">upgrade</button>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>


<script>
    var mouseclick = 1;
    var clickcounter = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var hp = 10;
    var kills = 0;

    var killdraw = document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = kills;
    var hpdraw = document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;
    document.getElementById("clicktest").innerHTML = clickcounter;
    document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;




    function onKlik() {
        clickcounter += mouseclick;
        hp -= mouseclick;
        document.getElementById("clicktekst").innerHTML = clickcounter;
        document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;

        if (hp<=0) {
            kills ++;
            hp = 10;
            document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;
            document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = kills;
           // hpdraw;
           // killdraw;

        }
    }

    function upgradeKlik() {
        while (i == 0 && clickcounter >= 10) {
            //mouseclick += 1;
            mouseclick ++;
            clickcounter -= 10;
            document.getElementById("clicktekst").innerHTML = clickcounter;
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. What would you use `hpdraw` and such for? The only place they occur in your code is a commented-out reference to them not doing anything with them.

Comment: You're not using `hpDraw` anywhere. What's the point of it?

Comment: To shorten the code, so i don't have to use document.getElementById every time. I'm terrible in explaining my problems, and i'm trying to get better at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment answering my *"What would you use hpdraw and such for?"* question:

> To shorten the code, so i don't have to use document.getElementById every time.

This line:

```
var hpdraw = document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp;
```

sets `hpdraw` to the *result* of `document.getElementById("hp-bar-p").innerHTML = hp`, which is the value of `hp`.

You probably want:

```
var hpdraw = document.getElementById("hp-bar-p");
hpdraw.innerHTML = hp
```

...and then `hpdraw.innerHTML = "something else"` where you want to update it again later.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation!